# How to display the Excel Cell content along with its styling in XHTML page?

Tags: html, apache-poi

I am developing a **Java Web Application** using **JSF, Primefaces and XHTML**.

In which, I am trying to read the **Cell** content from **Excel**  using **POI**. In cell, it contains some styling like (bold, color, line-through, underline and etc) along with the value.

So now, I need to show the value as well all the styles of the cell in **XHTML** page.

Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The style is either applied to the whole cell or to parts of the cell content in rich text string content.

If applied to the whole cell, the cell style has a [Font](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html) applied from which you can get the style.

For getting the styles from rich text string content, you need to get the [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html) from the cell. This consists of multiple formatting runs, each having a style having a `Font` applied. So you need looping over all formatting runs to get their styles and their `Font`s.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcelRichTextCells {

 static StringBuffer getHTMLFormatted(String textpart, Font font) {

  StringBuffer htmlstring = new StringBuffer();

  boolean wasbold = false;
  boolean wasitalic = false;
  boolean wasunderlined = false;
  boolean wassub = false;
  boolean wassup = false;

  if (font != null) {
   if (font.getBold() ) {
    htmlstring.append("<b>");
    wasbold = true;
   }
   if (font.getItalic()) {
    htmlstring.append("<i>");
    wasitalic = true;
   }
   if (font.getUnderline() == Font.U_SINGLE) {
    htmlstring.append("<u>");
    wasunderlined = true;
   }
   if (font.getTypeOffset() == Font.SS_SUB) {
    htmlstring.append("<sub>");
    wassub = true;
   }
   if (font.getTypeOffset() == Font.SS_SUPER) {
    htmlstring.append("<sup>");
    wassup = true;
   }
  } 

  htmlstring.append(textpart);

  if (wassup) {
   htmlstring.append("</sup>");
  }
  if (wassub) {
   htmlstring.append("</sub>");
  }
  if (wasunderlined) {
   htmlstring.append("</u>");
  }
  if (wasitalic) {
   htmlstring.append("</i>");
  }
  if (wasbold) {
   htmlstring.append("</b>");
  }
  return htmlstring;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelRichTextCells.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
     case STRING: //CellType String
      XSSFRichTextString richtextstring = (XSSFRichTextString)cell.getRichStringCellValue();

      String textstring = richtextstring.getString();

      StringBuffer htmlstring = new StringBuffer();

      if (richtextstring.hasFormatting()) {
       for (int i = 0; i < richtextstring.numFormattingRuns(); i++) {
        int indexofformattingrun = richtextstring.getIndexOfFormattingRun(i);
        String textpart = textstring.substring(indexofformattingrun, 
                                               indexofformattingrun + richtextstring.getLengthOfFormattingRun(i));
        Font font = richtextstring.getFontOfFormattingRun(i);
        // font might be null if no formatting is applied to the specified text run
        // then font of the cell should be used.
        if (font == null) font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
        htmlstring.append(getHTMLFormatted(textpart, font));
       }
      } else {
       Font font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
       htmlstring.append(getHTMLFormatted(textstring, font));
      } 

      System.out.println(htmlstring);
      break;

     //case ... other CellTypes

     default:
      System.out.println("default cell"); //should never occur
    }
   }
  }

  wb.close();

 }
}
```

---

This code was tested using `apache poi 3.17`.
For using this code with `apache poi 4.0.1` do using `CellStyle.getCellType` instead of `getCellTypeEnum`and `CellStyle.getFontIndexAsInt` instead of `getFontIndex`.

```
...
//switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
...
//Font font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
Font font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndexAsInt());
...
//if (font == null) font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
if (font == null) font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndexAsInt());
...
```

---

The following is a version which supports both, `XSSF` and `HSSF`. It is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.1`.

The only difference between `XSSF` and `HSSF` is while getting the font of formatting run. `XSSF` gets the font directly while `HSSF` gets the font index in the workbook only.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcelRichTextCells {

 static StringBuffer getHTMLFormatted(String textpart, Font font) {

  StringBuffer htmlstring = new StringBuffer();

  boolean wasbold = false;
  boolean wasitalic = false;
  boolean wasunderlined = false;
  boolean wassub = false;
  boolean wassup = false;

  if (font != null) {
   if (font.getBold() ) {
    htmlstring.append("<b>");
    wasbold = true;
   }
   if (font.getItalic()) {
    htmlstring.append("<i>");
    wasitalic = true;
   }
   if (font.getUnderline() == Font.U_SINGLE) {
    htmlstring.append("<u>");
    wasunderlined = true;
   }
   if (font.getTypeOffset() == Font.SS_SUB) {
    htmlstring.append("<sub>");
    wassub = true;
   }
   if (font.getTypeOffset() == Font.SS_SUPER) {
    htmlstring.append("<sup>");
    wassup = true;
   }
  } 

  htmlstring.append(textpart);

  if (wassup) {
   htmlstring.append("</sup>");
  }
  if (wassub) {
   htmlstring.append("</sub>");
  }
  if (wasunderlined) {
   htmlstring.append("</u>");
  }
  if (wasitalic) {
   htmlstring.append("</i>");
  }
  if (wasbold) {
   htmlstring.append("</b>");
  }
  return htmlstring;  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelRichTextCells.xlsx"));
  //Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelRichTextCells.xls"));

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    //switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
     case STRING: //CellType String
      RichTextString richtextstring = cell.getRichStringCellValue();

      String textstring = richtextstring.getString();

      StringBuffer htmlstring = new StringBuffer();
      
      if (richtextstring.numFormattingRuns() > 0) { // we have formatted runs
       if (richtextstring instanceof HSSFRichTextString) { // HSSF does not count first run as formatted run when it does not have formatting
        if (richtextstring.getIndexOfFormattingRun(0) != 0) { // index of first formatted run is not at start of text
         String textpart = textstring.substring(0, richtextstring.getIndexOfFormattingRun(0)); // get first run from index 0 to index of first formatted run
         Font font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex()); // use cell font 
         htmlstring.append(getHTMLFormatted(textpart, font));
        } 
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < richtextstring.numFormattingRuns(); i++) { // loop through all formatted runs
        // get index of frormatting run and index of next frormatting run
        int indexofformattingrun = richtextstring.getIndexOfFormattingRun(i);
        int indexofnextformattingrun = textstring.length();
        if ((i+1) < richtextstring.numFormattingRuns()) indexofnextformattingrun = richtextstring.getIndexOfFormattingRun(i+1);
        // formatted text part is the sub string from index of frormatting run to index of next frormatting run
        String textpart = textstring.substring(indexofformattingrun, indexofnextformattingrun);
        // determine used font
        Font font = null; 
        if (richtextstring instanceof XSSFRichTextString) {                                       
         font = ((XSSFRichTextString)richtextstring).getFontOfFormattingRun(i);
         // font might be null if no formatting is applied to the specified text run
         // then font of the cell should be used.
         if (font == null) font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
        } else if (richtextstring instanceof HSSFRichTextString) {
         short fontIndex = ((HSSFRichTextString)richtextstring).getFontOfFormattingRun(i);
         // font index might be HSSFRichTextString.NO_FONT if no formatting is applied to the specified text run
         // then font of the cell should be used.
         if (fontIndex == HSSFRichTextString.NO_FONT) {
          font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());   
         } else {
          font = wb.getFontAt(fontIndex); 
         }         
        }
        htmlstring.append(getHTMLFormatted(textpart, font));
       }
      } else {
       Font font = wb.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
       htmlstring.append(getHTMLFormatted(textstring, font));
      } 

      System.out.println(htmlstring);
      break;

     //case ... other CellTypes

     default:
      System.out.println("default cell"); //should never occur
    }
   }
  }

  wb.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thnq for reply and the style is parts of the cell content only.

Comment: This above code is works fine, but the output like this "<b><strike>explosion causing</b></strike>and<b><u>multiple values</b></u>". in that, the start and end tag is misplacing wrongly.

Comment: @venkat raj: Sorry, cannot reproducing. For me it works correct. But since I had not included strike-through at all, you seems have changed the code. Then you must pay attention on the order in `getHTMLFormatted`:  The last start tag appended must be the first end tag appended.

Comment: @– Axel Richter : Yeah now its working fine, I had changed the code as per my requirement.  I had an another one issue is that, the font.getBold() is not working fine on ubuntu machine when reading cell content from excel and it is created, styled in windows machine.

Comment: @venkat raj: Sorry, but I also cannot reproducing your next issue. My sample file `ExcelRichTextCells.xlsx` was created using `Excel` (2007 and 2016) in `Windows 10`. And my code runs always in `ubuntu linux` per default. And it works well.

Comment: @venkat raj: You could telling what exactly is your issue. Is an exception thrown? Which? What could be the reason is that in the ubuntu machine runs a lower version of `apache poi` which does not know `getBold()`. In earlier versions this was `getBoldWeight()`.

Comment: @– Axel Richter : There is no exception and I also tried with **getBoldWeight()**. I am using POI 3.9 version. plz see this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420464/how-to-find-styling-cell-content-from-excelcreated-in-windows-machine-on-ubunt)

Comment: @venkat raj: "I am using POI 3.9": Then I am out. I will not bothering myself with debugging for code for a nearly 6 years old `apache poi` version. The current stable version is `3.16`. You are ignoring nearly 6 yeard of development of `apache poi`. Good luck.

Comment: @– Axel Richter : You mean, If I update the version means It will be work right?.

Comment: @venkat raj: As said, my code works well. But your code in your new question is very different from mine and I don't know exactly why the single changings were made. I cannot following your thoughts while you had made those changings. For me your new code is wrong in multiple parts. So no guarantee for your code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@Axel**, as his answer didn't include **color** so I decided to add it. But unfortunately in my case, `font.getColor()` always returned '0'. 
I went through another way as this:

```
static StringBuffer getHTMLFormatted(String textpart, Font font) {

    StringBuffer htmlstring = new StringBuffer();
    ...
    boolean hasColor = false;
    ...
    if(font.toString().contains("<main:color rgb")) { 
              String color = getColor(font);
              htmlstring.append("<font color=#").append(color).append(">") ;
              hasColor = true ;
        }

   }

    htmlstring.append(textpart);
    ...
    if (hasColor) {
        htmlstring.append("</font>");
    }
    return htmlstring;
}

public static String getColor(Font font){
        String colorStr ;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<main:color rgb=\"(.*?)\"/>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(font.toString());
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            Log.i(TAG , "font color = : " + matcher.group(1));
            colorStr = matcher.group(1);
            colorStr = colorStr.substring(2);
        }else {
            colorStr = "616A6B" ; // my defualt color
        }

        return colorStr;
}
```