# reading text along with formatting from excel cell using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read ms-excel sheet cell value which contains RichText. Example below.

Welcome to **apache-poi** *world*.
       Please use latest version of poi.

As you can see the word contains bold and italic word and new paragraph. I want to read this text along with style format, So that i can display in UI the way i have entered.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375213/how-to-display-the-excel-cell-content-along-with-its-styling-in-xhtml-page/49376583#49376583