# Reading Font inside of an Excel-Cell with Apache-POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In my Java Code I'm trying to extract some font information inside of a cell in an .xlsx file using Apache-POI. I just need to retrieve which substrings of the string-cell are bold.

The problem is that my code is only working when the cell doesn't start with a bold word.

I use following (simplified) code:

```
XSSFRichTextString formatted = (XSSFRichTextString)cell.getRichStringCellValue();

formatted.getFontAtIndex(0).getBold(); //line 1 
formatted.getFontAtIndex(22).getBold(); //line 2
```

The content of the cell I'm reading looks like this: 
"**1st-String** 2nd-String **3rd-String** ecc ..."

22 is the index where 3rd-String starts.
Line 1 returns (unexpected) false, while line 2 returns (expected) true.

What am I missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375213/how-to-display-the-excel-cell-content-along-with-its-styling-in-xhtml-page/49376583#49376583. Try getting the formatting runs of the rich text string and the font out of the single formatting runs then.

Comment: The font of the formatted run might be null if no formatting is applied to the specified text run. In your example this can be the case if the whole cell is bold and only parts are not bold, in opposite to the whole cell is not bold and only parts are bold. Then, if  font of the formatted run id null, font of the cell should be used. I have updated my code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375213/how-to-display-the-excel-cell-content-along-with-its-styling-in-xhtml-page/49376583#49376583.