# Facing issue while displaying Excel Cell content along with its styling in XHTML page

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying the solution provided by @Axel Richter at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375213/how-to-display-the-excel-cell-content-along-with-its-styling-in-xhtml-page) to display the cell content along with the styling.

The code is working fine for me in case of bold, italics,underlined data but **it can't detect line break within a cell**. So it is rendering all the data in a single line.

For example, if I have a cell data(which has line break in between) like given below

Model Year : test

Model Year : test

The above data is coming in a single line(Model Year : test  Model Year : test).

Can anyone suggest the way to add a linebreak/paragraph tag to distinguish two-line within cell?

Thanks in an advance

Comment: What have you tried? If the line feeds are contained in the cells, then it is as simple as: `static StringBuffer getHTMLFormatted(String textpart, Font font) {...  if (textpart.contains("\n")) textpart = textpart.replace("\n", "<br/>"); htmlstring.append(textpart);  ...` using my linked code.

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you. It's working for me.