# Apache POI : Using formatted text from XLSX file to create DOCX

Tags: apache-poi

Using Apache POI, I need to create a .docx file using text extracted from a .xlsx spreadsheet. Everything goes well for simple text and data.

The problem is that some cells have formatted text, where I can easily retrieve a `XSSFRichTextString` object. I need to keep this formatting in the output .docx document.

The code is too long and complex to post here, but basically I end up with `XWPFParagraph` object and the `XSSFRichTextString` object that must go into it. It is my understanding that text must be added through `XWPFRun` objects to the `XWPFParagraph` object.

Another issue is that I'm stuck on the Apache POI 3.16.

Can this be done ?

Comment: You need traversing the formatting runs of `XSSFRichtextString` and creating `XWPFRun`s from them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375213/how-to-display-the-excel-cell-content-along-with-its-styling-in-xhtml-page/49376583#49376583 for how to traverse the  formatting runs of `XSSFRichtextString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer so I can add the code, but the solution is based on [How to display the Excel Cell content along with its styling in XHTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375213), as suggested by Axel Richter in the comment.

```
// from caller
XSSFRichTextString  richTextString;
XSSFCellStyle       cellStyle;

String textString = richTextString.getString();

for (int i = 0; i < richTextString.numFormattingRuns(); i++) {
    int nTextPos = richTextString.getIndexOfFormattingRun(i);
    String textPart = textString.substring(nTextPos, nTextPos + richTextString.getLengthOfFormattingRun(i));
    Font font = richTextString.getFontOfFormattingRun(i);

    boolean withLineBreak = false;
    do {
        XWPFRun _run = p.createRun();

        String sThisPart = textPart;
        
        // break into multiple strings
        int nNewLinePos = textPart.indexOf("\n");
        if (nNewLinePos != -1) {
            sThisPart = textPart.substring(0, nNewLinePos);
            textPart = textPart.substring(nNewLinePos + 1);
        }
        else {
            textPart = "";
        }
        
        if (withLineBreak) {
            _run.addBreak();
        }

        _run.setText(sThisPart);

        if (font != null) {
            // from richtextstring
            _run.setFontFamily(font.getFontName());
            _run.setBold(font.getBold());
            _run.setItalic(font.getItalic());
        }
        else if (cellStyle != null) {
            // from cell style
            _run.setFontFamily(cellStyle.getFont().getFontName());
            _run.setBold(cellStyle.getFont().getBold());
            _run.setItalic(cellStyle.getFont().getItalic());
        }
        
        p.addRun(_run);
        withLineBreak = true;
    }
    while (!textPart.isEmpty());
}
```

Be aware that some properties from the `Font` object must be converted to usable data in the text run, like font sizes, for example.

One could set mote text properties from the rich text to the document run. For me it worked fine like this.